# Getting "app.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function" in a javascript calculator I'm trying to make

Tags: javascript

I've linked up the html and css but keep getting this error at these lines in the code for some reason 
    `at btnMaker (app.js:44)
    at app.js:8
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`
at init (app.js:6)
I had made this calculator in pure javascript but created a HTMl and CSS front end for it and changed some things around but am stuck as to what I did wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
const opts = ['*', '/', '+', '-', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0', '.']; //all keys
const spec = ['*', '/', '+', '-']; //special function keys
function init() {

  opts.forEach(function (val) {
    //console.log(val);
    btnMaker(val, addOutput);
  })
  btnMaker('=', evalOutput);
  btnMaker('C', clrOutput);

  function cOutput(v) {
    output.style.border = v + ' 1px solid';
    output.style.color = v;
  }

  function evalOutput() {
    cOutput('black');
    console.log('=');
    if (output.value === "") {
      cOutput('red');
    }
    else if (eva) {
      cOutput('red');
    }
    else {
      output.value = eval(output.value);
    }
    dec = output.value.includes('.');
  }

  function clrOutput() {
    cOutput('black');
    output.value = "";
  }

  function btnMaker(txt, myFunction) {
    let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON');
      console.log(btn);

    btn.val = txt;
    btn.textContent = txt;
    btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
//    main.appendChild(btn);
  }

  function addOutput(e) {
//    console.log(dec);
    cOutput('black');
    //console.log(e.target.val);
    let char = e.target.val;
    if (char == '.') {
      if (dec) {
        char = '';
        cOutput('red');
      }
      else {
        dec = true;
      }
    }
    eva = spec.includes(char);
    if (eva) {
      dec = false;
    }
    output.value += char;
  }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName its a plural - you still treat it as one, check first item

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a collection -  to access a single button you need to btn[0]

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
const opts = ['*', '/', '+', '-', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0', '.']; //all keys
const spec = ['*', '/', '+', '-']; //special function keys
function init() {

  opts.forEach(function (val) {
    //console.log(val);
    btnMaker(val, addOutput);
  })
  btnMaker('=', evalOutput);
  btnMaker('C', clrOutput);

  function cOutput(v) {
    output.style.border = v + ' 1px solid';
    output.style.color = v;
  }

  function evalOutput() {
    cOutput('black');
    console.log('=');
    if (output.value === "") {
      cOutput('red');
    }
    else if (eva) {
      cOutput('red');
    }
    else {
      output.value = eval(output.value);
    }
    dec = output.value.includes('.');
  }

  function clrOutput() {
    cOutput('black');
    output.value = "";
  }

  function btnMaker(txt, myFunction) {
    const main = document.getElementById('#main')
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(txt)
    const btn = document.createElement('Button')
    btn.appendChild(textNode);
    btn.value = txt;
    
    console.log(btn);
    btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }

  function addOutput(e) {
//    console.log(dec);
    cOutput('black');
    //console.log(e.target.val);
    let char = e.target.val;
    if (char == '.') {
      if (dec) {
        char = '';
        cOutput('red');
      }
      else {
        dec = true;
      }
    }
    eva = spec.includes(char);
    if (eva) {
      dec = false;
    }
    output.value += char;
  }
}
```

Check the btnMaker function after running.

Comment: Hey, @idz22211
I'm not sure where you are going to place your buttons but check this code result

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')
```

This will return an array of buttons (HTMLCollection).
In order to add the event listener you must pick which index in collection you are attaching it to if it is only one it would be 0.
so the correct way of changing the value and text content would be

```
let btnCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON');
btnCollection[0].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Or you can use ID selector for specific button;

```
let btn = document.getElementById('my-special-button')
```

Comment: ah ok could I attach the event listener to all of them at once?

Comment: a for loop to cycle through?